# Is it possible to use right headphone as left?

Tags: audio, headphones

I have two headphones. Both of which have only the right headphone (R) working. I somehow got both the headphones to work together (as a single unit). But the problem is that since they are both right headphones they output the same sound. If some sound is made on the left side, it is completely inaudible to me since both of them output the sounds at the right side (which also makes it seems like the same sound is coming from both the directions).

Is there any way in which I can make one of the Right headphones work as if they were left? Such that one of them would output left sound, even though it is a right headphone.

**P.S.:-** Btw I have [Sony MDR-ZX110A On-Ear Stereo Headphones](https://www.amazon.in/Sony-MDR-ZX110A-Stereo-Headphones-without/dp/B00KGZZ824/) if that helps. Also I forgot the mention how I am using both the headphones together as one. What I did is I first plugged both the Right side headphones in a single unit. This lead to my headphone having two aux cables rather then one. So I plug both of them onto my PC to use them together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to wire them correctly. Cut off the existing headphone jacks and wire the headphone wires to a single headphone jack. The tip is the left audio channel, the first ring (after the tip) is right. The next ring (or sleeve if that's what's next) is ground, which the shield braid of both wires should be attached to.